# Google Docs viewer disable download

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, google-docs

Please take a look at this link

http://jsfiddle.net/C7Py6/3/

The last icon on google viewer's toolbar - [image] enables user to view on new browser window and download PDF. The question is, how can I make it view only and disable download (At least disable this toolbar item). Is that possible with google viewer? or is there any other viewer that works like Google Viewer but view-only?

Answer (score 8):

You can host your PDF files on Google Docs and prevent viewer downloads. To do this do followings:

1. Once you login into your Google Docs account at docs.google.com website, you should see listing of documents in your account. Right click specific document that you want to secure by disabling download option.
2. Then click on “prevent viewers from downloading” option. This will remove downloading option and other users viewing the document cannot download the document file as a whole and reproduce its copy.

[image]

Also note, since you can only prevent downloading of documents created by you, click ‘Owned by Me’ option on left side. This will display document created and owned by you. Then you can disable and prevent document downloading option for files on display.

Then you can just share this PDF on your website. IT will be **view only**. The code will look like that:

```
<iframe src="url to pdf/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to control all features of Google Apps http://www.saasid.com/what-we-do/saasid-for-google-apps/

Application feature control gives organisations full management of application features and functions with no complex changes to theapplication back-end. Tabs, menu options, buttons and links can be can be disabled or removed from view, or their use can simply be monitored and logged. Application feature control features for Google Apps include:

Gmail can be made corporate-only,
File attach to Gmail messages can be removed,
Chat boxes removed,
Sharing options removed from menu or document editor in Google Drive

Comment: It would be better to include code/examples/an explanation here and provide the link as backup for more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

This technique will still allow the user to "make a copy" and with ownership this brings they can then download as they please. Not tested this, but I'm pretty sure I'm right...

Comment: what technique are you talking about?