# How to hide the download option from a Google Doc while viewing a document using a WebView?

Tags: android, google-docs

The following code has the download option on the page. I want to remove this option and only give accessors permission to read not download.

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.WebView01);
String pdfurl = ""; // Url of pdf or doc file.

String weblink="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+pdfurl;    
mWebView.loadUrl(weblink);
```

Comment: You can change the setting in Docs on a specific document to prevent download (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108585/google-docs-viewer-disable-download)

Comment: how come you get a download option? I've tried with this link and I get no download on PC nor phone (it launches the Drive app)  https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro7_pg_ue.pdf Please provide an example

Answer (score 2):

Use http connection parse html using jsoup ....catch the tag under which download link is and disable it ... it take  sec to parse but effectivly working...

Answer (score 0):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
            @Override 
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                        String description, String failingUrl) {

            } 

            @Override 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true; 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + 
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; })()"); 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            } 
        })
```